# Android - EditText is adjusting when data is inputted

Tags: android

Quite a weird situation where when the user inputs text into the edit text, instead of populating like normal the edittext is getting wider with each input

Screenshot 1 is before

[image: Before]

Then screenshot 2 shows how the edittext has gotten bigger instead of filling the available space

[image: After]

Any idea's as to why it's doing this?

Here is my xml for the edittext

```
 <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/text_name"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.47" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `weight` (on a horizontal `LinearLayout`) you need to specify the width to be equal to `0dp` rather `wrap_content`:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

keep android:layout_width="0dp" as 0dp then weight work properly

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/text_name"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.47" />
```